# Posting links to FB from Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-share

I am trying to post a link to FB in Unity using the FB SDK.

First I used the example given

```
        FB.FeedShare(
        null,
        new Uri("https://developers.facebook.com/"),
        "title",
        "caption",
        "description",
        new Uri("https://imgur.com/a/IUwesX7"),
        null,
        HandleResult);
```

This works perfectly - link gets posted and has a preview picture (take from the first link). In fact, the link works so well that clicking on the pic opens MY app even though the page has no meta tags pointing to my app! How does that happen?

However, when I replace the links with my own it doesn't work:

```
        FB.FeedShare(
        null,
        new Uri("http://anykey.co.il/deeplinks/duckduckduck.html/"),
        "title",
        "caption",
        "description",
        new Uri("http://anykey.co.il/deeplinks/feature.png"),
        null,
        HandleResult);
```

The link works ok but I don't get a preview picture. I get a placeholder with the name of my site. The placeholder is clickable and opens my app on my device but there is no pic

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<HEAD>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <TITLE></TITLE>
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="duckduckduck://story/1234">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="il.co.anykey.games.duckgames.duckduckduck">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="DuckDuckDuck">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Duck Duck Duck" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ye/r/lWB96Z8sFtt.png" />
  <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
    body{font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.4em;color:#333;background-color:White;}
  </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<A><IMG SRC="feature.png"></A>
<H1></H1>

<HR>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is what I see when posting from my app:
[image]

Even stranger, if I copy the HTML from the FB link and put it on my site I get no picture.

What am I missing here? Does my website need to be authorised or something?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ If you are really using an og:image from the Facebook CDN, that won’t work, pretty sure they have a restriction on using those for that purpose. Use an image hosted somewhere else.

Comment: I tried. Besides the image used in the one in the page and not the image you link to.

Comment: Wait, you mean that you get the image that you specified as og:image in the meta tags? That’s how it is supposed to work, you can not set those values dynamically at the time of sharing any more; that will only work if you post to a Facebook _page_ that has claimed ownership of the content first, for sharing on user profiles this is not possible any more.

Comment: The problem is I DON'T get the image I put. In og:image tag. It completely ignored it. This is true for any page I link to iit is hosted on my server. Even if I take FB's own own page which works when hosted by them but not when hosted by me.

Comment: Well then check it via the debug tool!

Comment: What debug tool you mean?

Comment: The one I posted the link to at the very beginning of the very first comment …!?!

Answer (score 0):

After burning many hours it turned out that removing the "/" from the end of my Url solved the problem.
Not sure why that is but now it is all working well.